# Error in LINQ statement when building

Tags: c#, linq

In the following LINQ statement I get the error :

**Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'bool'**

The 3rd last line has a blue line under the entire line. Here is the code, I tried various changes, i must be missing something obvious, thanks in advance...

```
var allWaste = _securityRepository.FindAllWaste(userId, SystemType.W);

        var searchResults = (
                from s in allWaste
                where
                (
                    from x in _db.WasteIndicatorItems
                      join y in 
                        _db.WasteIndicators 
                       on x.WasteIndicatorId equals y.WasteIndicatorId
                      join z in 
                        _db.HazardTypes 
                       on y.HazardTypeId equals z.HazardTypeId
                    where
                        s.WasteId == x.WasteId
                    group new { x, z } by new { x.WasteId, z.Hazardous } into g
                    select new
                    {
                        nbrOf = g.Count(),
                        g.Key.Hazardous
                    }
                ).Where(a => a.nbrOf >= 1 && a.Hazardous == false)
                select s
            ).Distinct();
```

Comment: (1) If you remove the distinct, what is the type that is returned? What is the type of `s`? It's hard to guess when we don't know you type definitions. (2) If you put a code snippet, it's hard to read when it scrolls horizontally. Making it fit (like I did) makes it easy on the eyes :)

Comment: Also, what about encapsulating `s` with `).Where(a => a.nbrOf >= 1 && a.Hazardous == false)` (IOW, your where is AFTER `s`

Comment: I don't use Linq's query syntax, but it almost seems that your first where clause [from s in allWaste where] is expecting a predicate/boolean, but you've given it another table/subquery instead. I would start with testing your sub query by itself first, then add in the allwaste table after verifying that the subquery works

Comment: @jlnorsworthy I didn't notice that at all!! Good catch!

Comment: If I remove the distinct it returns an IEnumerable, i want an IQueryable<waste> as per procedure header

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have an IQueryable in your where clause.

Try

```
...where( (from x in _db.WasteIndicators ... ).Any() )...
```

Or something that returns a boolean.